# How do I unsign an apk that has had zipalign run on it?

Tags: android, apk

I've created a script that does some final packaging on an APK file, using the output from two different build processes to create a final APK that has the content from one build inserted into the APK from the other build.

If the input APK has been signed, I un-sign it by deleting the META-INF folder in the APK (and then go on to the rest of the script).  The problem is that if the input APK was both signed and "zipalign"ed, the output APK has some corrupted files in it, which is bad.

Does "zipalign"ing prevent future changes to the APK?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works, you can unzip the APK, delete the META-INF folder, then re-zip the rest.

Comment: Alas, it seems that the APK is entirely corrupted after editing; when I used WinRAR to do some editing of the APK, it corrupted some of the icons, and they're no longer any good.  So, apparently, zip-aligning an APK renders it un-editable.